# Couchbase-Append to a Collection in JSON Document

Tags: couchbase

How to append data to a Collection which is already existing JSON document using Java SDK?

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently a json append feature in Couchbase so you will need to get the docuemnt, modify it, and then re-insert it back into the database. You can also use cas operations in order to make sure no other clients are updating the document concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for answering. To update of few members in a huge document(in size), needs to load entire document from Couchbase Node into Server and send it back to the Node. I think it leads to performance overhead, network overhead. This design suggests to have small documents. Here is a caveat. Having small documents in huge number needs more memory to maintain keys/metadata information in Couchbase Server memcache. Which design do you suggest? Small/Big document size.

Comment: I tend to recommend using smaller documents as a general best case solution, but this really depends on your application. How many documents do you think you will have? What is the memory quota on each node? Also, how much of the large document will your application actually use when it gets the whole document? I think it might be a good idea to post a separate questions with more details about your use case then I can answer it there.

Answer (score 1):

I have a nice thing that I use but it's something that need to handle by code.
I wrote my prepend/append in couchbase 2.x
you can use legacy document and do prepend to the JSON with ","
when you take it out you need to put "[" "]" and then you will get JSON list with the data"
when value is a JSON that I want to put in a list.

```
try {
    bucket.prepend(LegacyDocument.create(key, value + ","));
} catch (Exception e){
    //if fails first insert the basic JSON first.
    bucket.insert(LegacyDocument.create(key, value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have some sort of an efficient solution for this.

How about, first storing everything in a temporary database using bytestreams (non-json values). This way, you could basically append the values as you would like. After your append operations are completed (let's say at the end of a bulk data load), you could execute a small program to retrieve all the keys in the json one by one and convert it to the json value and insert to our new database (you could even use the existing one).

This is a workaround obviously, but far more efficient than querying it everytime.

Cheers,